# an available of (quick question)

Tags: adjectives, nouns

Is it grammatically correct to write

"based on an available of an item or a service?"

If it is wrong, how about 'based on the available of an item or a service?"

please help me.

Comment: Any dictionary should tell you that *available* is an adjective and that the noun form is *availability*.

Comment: Thanks.. I just wondered whether there were any other form or usage of "available". Thanks.~

Comment: Well, there is a longer version: "based on the assumption that (an item or service) is/will be available."

Answer (score 1):

Available is not a noun and following sentences you wrote are incorrect:

> Based on an available of an item or a service
>
> Based on the available of an item or a service

Grammatical sentences are:

> Based on the ***availability*** of an item or a service

And

> Based on the assumption that an item or a service is ***available*** (as WhatRoughBeast has said)

You can also write:

> (It is) based on whether or not an item or a service is ***available***.

Here, you can use the adjective 'available' in the sentence.

Comment: Did you mean to say that _available_ is **not** a noun?

Comment: Please check my first and last sentences. @BrianHitchcock

Comment: I was putting it too politely. _Available_ is NOT a noun. If it were, the OP's sentences would be grammatically correct; but as you noted, they are not.

Comment: Again, you're right. It was my misunderstanding. Actually, I said it correctly in my answer, but could not get your comment. Yes, *Available* is an adjective, while *Availability* is a noun. Appreciate your effort to point out my mistake.

Comment: Hate to say it, but you're still calling "available" a noun in the last sentence.

Comment: @CrazyEyes please check the answer now. I have corrected the mistake that you and Brian have pointed out.